# Swift enum's unwrapping by reference

Tags: swift, enums, option-type

I'm new to Swift and decided to write my own Optional enum.

```
enum MyOptional<Type> {
    case none
    case some(Type)

    func get() -> Type {
        switch self {
        case .some(let x):
            return x
        case .none:
            fatalError()
        }
    }
}

var test: MyOptional<String> = MyOptional.some("testString")
test.get().append("#")
```

But in case I put some struct that have mutating function and call that function - the compiler, obviously, tells me:

> error: cannot use mutating member on immutable value: function call
>   returns immutable value test.get().append("#")

How does Swift's Optional returns struct by reference unwrapping them?

Comment: Why don't you just assign the value to a mutable variable and mutate that? `var testVal = test.get(); testVal.append("#")` works fine. Moreover, since Swift is an open source language if you're unsure how something is achieved, you can always check the source code.

Comment: It sounds like this is a learning experience - and a valid one - OP wants to be able to reconstruct something like `var myString: String? = "a"; myString?.append("b")`.

It seems possible to me that this is something Apple is leveraging compiler magic to do that might not be possible to reimplement - but I might be totally wrong there.

Comment: Optionals are treated specially by the compiler. Example: `struct A { } ; let a: Optional<A> = A()` – you can assign a non-optional to an optional.

Comment: @DávidPásztor yes, I'm just interested how to reconstruct the sequence of manual unwrapping and setting a new value to `test` var. To make the one line code as it allows swift.

Comment: @DávidPásztor actually, I've checked the sources and the is a function, that do almost the same as I do: `public var unsafelyUnwrapped: Wrapped {
    @inline(__always)
    get {
      if let x = self {
        return x
      }
    ...
    }
  }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Swift compiler has quite a bit of built-in support for `Optional`; including for the postfix operators `!` and `?` which can produce l-values (values which reside at known locations in memory; therefore allowing for mutations of that memory if the expression is mutable).

Unfortunately I don't believe it's possible to implement your own l-value returning operators (or functions in general), although constructs that allow you to define getters and setters (such as computed properties and subscripts) can be treated as l-values when they have setters:

```
enum MyOptional<Type> {

  case none, some(Type)

  var forceUnwrapped: Type {
    get {
      switch self {
      case .some(let x):
        return x
      case .none:
        fatalError()
      }
    }
    set {
      self = .some(newValue)
    }
  }

  // just for demonstration; don't actually implement this as a subscript!
  subscript() -> Type {
    get {
      switch self {
      case .some(let x):
        return x
      case .none:
        fatalError()
      }
    }
    set {
      self = .some(newValue)
    }
  }
}

var test = MyOptional.some("testString")
test.forceUnwrapped.append("#")
test[].append("#")
```

Here, `test.forceUnwrapped` and `test[]` can be treated as l-values. When mutating through them, the compiler will create a temporary variable from calling the getter, mutate this temporary, and then call the setter with the mutated value.

Although it's worth noting in both cases that when used with assignment
 (i.e `test.forceUnwrapped = ...` & `test[] = ...`), the getter won't be called; only the setter, which gives them slightly different semantics to `Optional`'s postfix `!`, which will crash on the optional being `nil` even on assignment (i.e `someOptional! = ...`).

As an alternative, you could also define a method that takes a closure with an `inout` parameter, allowing the caller to mutate the force-unwrapped value:

```
enum MyOptional<Type> {

  case none
  case some(Type)

  mutating func forceMutate<R>(_ body: (inout Type) throws -> R) rethrows -> R {
    switch self {
    case .some(var x):
      defer {
        self = .some(x)
      }
      return try body(&x)
    case .none:
      fatalError()
    }
  }
}

var test = MyOptional.some("testString")
test.forceMutate { $0.append("#") }
```

Comment: I was thinking of how perhaps a custom infix operator (to act as `?`) can be combined with @autoclosure to produce `optional?.conditionallyChain()` behaviour. The right side of the expression isn't itself a valid expression, unforuntately.

Comment: @Alexander Yeah unfortunately it'd have to be a closure rhs, something like `optional <custom operator> { $0.append("#") }`, at which point you're probably better off with a method than an operator. `@autoclosure` can only deal with functions of the form `() -> T` (i.e no l-value like behaviour).

Comment: I was thinking you could have the operator do some pretty crazy shit. I'll use `?`, but it'll have to use some other sigil instead. My idea was that it would look like this: `myOptional?String.append("x")`, but it would parse as `(myOptional ? String.append)("x")`, so that it will produce a closure which has `String.append` bound to the `String` instance found within `myOptional`, which will (when called by `("x")`) perform the final step of calling `String.append`, and doing the assignment. I suspect this won't work, because escaping closures can't have structs by inout reference

Comment: Worth noting that this `[]` expression isn't returning an l-value, it's a `get` and `set` rolled together

Comment: @Alexander That's a really interesting idea! Although I believe it's held back by (1) As you say, mutating methods are realised as `(inout Type) -> (Args...) -> Ret` when accessed at static level, which are useless as `inout` only lasts for the duration of the first call (attempting to prolong is UB), (2) I believe it'd require variadic generics to handle any argument list to be passed through the operator....

Comment: ... If there was a nice way to reverse the currying of mutating methods at static level, e.g `(Args...) -> (inout Type) -> Ret`, then you'd be able to apply w/ args, and then pass `(inout Type) -> Ret` to the operator, which would work just fine like `test <custom op> String.specialAppend("x")`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160215/discussion-between-alexander-and-hamish).

Answer (score 1):

You can use non-mutating operations, and reassign the result back into the variable:

```
enum MyOptional<Type> {
    case none
    case some(Type)

    func forceUnwrap() -> Type {
        switch self {
        case .some(let x):
            return x
        case .none:
            fatalError()
        }
    }


    static func ?? (lhs: MyOptional, rhs: @autoclosure () -> Void) {

    }
}

var test: MyOptional<String> = .some("testString")
print(test)

test = .some(test.forceUnwrap() + "#")
print(test)
```

It might also be useful to have functions like `map` and `flatMap`:

```
extension MyOptional {
    func map(_ transform: (Wrapped) -> Wrapped) -> MyOptional<Wrapped> {
        switch self {
        case .some(let x):
            return .some(transform(x))
        case .none:
            return .none
        }
    }

    mutating func mapInPlace(_ transform: (Wrapped) -> Wrapped) {
        self = self.map(transform)
    }
}

test = test.map{ $0 + "#" }
print(test)

test.mapInPlace{ $0 + "#" }
print(test)
```

Comment: Yes, I understand that I can reassign. Was just interested, if I could make one line code, as `test!.append("#")`.